# como guardar datos locales de una base de datos MySql en C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Estoy desarrollando un programa que conecta con una base de datos en un pequeño servidor, el problema aqui es que el catalogo de productos son 15000 registros y cada que se quiere realizar alguna operacion se tiene que hacer consultas a dicha tabla lo cual me parece innecesario , pues es solo mantener ocupado el servidor, hay alguna forma de guardar los datos de las tablas de forma local, para no tener que estar consultando al servidor cada que se hace algo??

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres evitar tener que ir todo el tiempo a la db cuando la info que consultas no cambia seguido, para esto se usa tecnicas de `Cache`

Usando un servidor de cache local como ser `Redis` puede resolver el problema

[redis.io](https://redis.io/)

Entonces despues de instalar el servidor que si te animas podrias usar `docker` para que sea mas simple

Desde codigo agregas la referencia a nuget

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Cómo almacenar el elemento de la lista en caché de Redis](https://rstopup.com/como-almacenar-el-elemento-de-la-lista-en-cache-de-redis.html)

La idea es que valides si la `key` existe en redis, si esta presente recuperas el dato y no vas realizas la consulta a la db

El cache al ser local es mucho mas rapido que consultar la db